# Table Grid Created From JSON - Best search way

Tags: jquery, json

I create a table grid according to a json array and it's done.

What i want to know is:
what is the best and fastest way to search inside this table (hide/show rows)?

- is that if i remove all rows and search inside json then append new rows?
- or just search inside table and hide the unmatched rows?

Answer (score 2):

The fastest is hiding non-matching rows with CSS `display:none` or similar because it does not involve any DOM structure modification. Detaching all rows and attaching them on the go would cause many page redraws and thus would be potentially heavy on the CPU.

As for the searching itself, it's best to search through the JSON. Searching through the table (as a collection of DOM nodes) implies some DOM scraping, which again is way slower than just iterating over an array.